# como puedo recorrer el objeto de un api externa con angular js

Tags: angularjs, api, http

Hola estoy trabajando con un api con el servicio de angular http y obtengo el api endpoint, url=api/v2/{endpoint} pero no puedo recorrer el objeto que contiene esta url ya que para acceder a cada elemento tengo que acceder a api/v2/{endpoint}/1/, api/v2/{endpoint}/2/ ... y así sucesivamente quisiera saber si hay algún método para poder obtener todos los objetos de esta url para poderlos renderizar en html con ng-repeat por que de lo contrario no puedo acceder a este recurso.

```js
var app = angular.module('miApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/")
    .then(function(response) {
        $scope.datos = response.data;
    });
});
```

Gracias

Como la url es un endpoint general entonces tengo que acceder a cada objeto pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/ ... pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/2/... pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/3/... y asi sucesivamente. La respuesta que obtengo de pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/ es una lista de objetos que contiene una propiedad url y una propiedad name obtengo en la propiedad url = pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1 y en la propiedad name = bulbasaur entonces solo puedo acceder a estos dos objetos pero cuando accedo a la url directamente pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/ puedo obtener todos los objetos de este objeto que son a los que necesito acceder pero entonces quisiera saber como puedo recorrer todos los objetos de http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/ y asignarlos a una data para despues acederlos en html con ng-repeat= obj in data {{obj.name}} {{obj.description}} y asi sucesivamente gracias

Comment: puedes mostrar un ejemplo como esta llegando tu respuesta.